# c3p0 Connection pool memory leak redeploy tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, c3p0

I have these codes for closing c3p0 connection manager but it seems that there is still one more thread that was not closed . Am i missing something ?

```
Oct 11, 2016 5:12:09 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 11 17:11:58 PHT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2016-10-11 17:12:09 - [INFO ] CRMContextListener - Trying to Close
2016-10-11 17:12:09 - [INFO ] CRMContextListener - Close Success
Oct 11, 2016 5:12:09 PM      org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Oct 11 17:11:44 PHT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 11, 2016 5:12:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered. Oct 11, 2016 5:12:09 PM     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2xjsis9j1do3mrp1m3tqb8|fb6fd9c]-DeferredStatementDestroyerThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

This is the code for my servlet listener

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    logger.info("Trying to Close");

    for (Object o : C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources()) {
        try {
            ((PooledDataSource) o).close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("No thread was open...");
        }
    }

    logger.info("Close Success");
}
```

And here is my configuration for c3p0 xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sph-pdc-vm  1042:1521:DEV" />
    <property name="user" value="TSW" />
    <property name="password" value="TSW2015#" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100" />
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="5" />
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="10" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <property name="statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads" value="1" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="2" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="2000" />
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: The Pool data source cleanup indeed helps.  Thank you so much!            

`for (Object o : C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources()) {
        try {
            ((PooledDataSource) o).close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("No thread was open...");
        }
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely not to be a real memory leak, but a miswarning because c3p0's Threads take some time to wind down, and `close()` does not wait for that to complete, it's asynchronous. So you have an annoying message. See [this github issue](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/issues/79), thanks to Buğra Gedik on github. If you want to test this theory, you might add a delay of a second or so [i.e. call `Thread.sleep(1000)`] after your call to `close()` and see if the message goes away.

Although I don't think this is your issue, you might consider also adding some Tomcat parameters to be sure that attempts to close() the Threads always succeed. Just add...

```
<property name="privilegeSpawnedThreads" value="true" />
<property name="contextClassLoaderSource" value="library" />
```

See [c3p0's docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_avoid_memory_leaks_on_redeploy).

Comment: I tried calling the Thread.sleep(1000) after the close(). But the message is still there.

Comment: This actually solves the issue , your theory is correct !!! I just increase the time delay to 3000 and the log for memory leak disappears ! Thanks !

Comment: additional question . does undeploying application in tomcat should decrease the perm gen space ? because when i try to undeploy my application. the perm gen increase by 2mb. and when i redeploy my application . it increases by 20mb.